# define a "dependently typed" module functor

Tags: coq

How can I make a dependently typed functor (for lack of a better term) ? I want to do something like the following:

```
Module Type Element.
  ...
End Element.

Module Wrapper (E : Element).
  ...
End Wrapper.

Module DepentlyTypedFunctor (E : Element) (W : Wrapper E).
  ...
End DepentlyTypedFunctor.
```

The last definition doesn't work, and I guess I'm looking for the correct syntax, if possible at all. My motivation for this kind of definition is to define theorems inside `DependentlyTypedFunctor` that work for all `Wrappers` that contain any instance of `Element`, similar to how one could define a theorem for vectors, `forall (E : Element) (W : Wrapper E), some_proposition E W`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just meant to make `Wrapper` a `Module Type`. If it's not a module type, there's only one such module and you can just write `DependentlyTypedFunctor` over `E`. This might not be sufficient if you have opaque implementations of `Element`, though, in which case different instantiations of `Wrapper` might not be equal to each other.

If this is a problem, you might just want to use records instead of modules.

Comment: Defining Wrapper as a Module Type was sufficient, I was missing that.